# Dictionary attack implementation

Tags: c

I've found a function which takes as input an ASCII type string and return a value (as string). Doing some `strings` on the DLL I was able to find a couple of keys, however I would like to discover other possibilities.

The function is:

```
long    GetValue(LPCSTR in_key, LPSTR out_value, long in_buflen);
```

to test the key is valid:

```
char buf[512];
long ret;
const char ref[] = "ABC";
ret = GetValue(ref, b, 512);
if( ret )
  {
  printf( "Ok: [%s -> %s]\n", ref, b );
  }
```

Doing exhaustive search is too slow. What tools can I use (I am on linux+wine) to setup a dictionary based attack on this function ?

So far all keys I've found are upper Camel Case (no space).

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary attacks are not good for this. It is not uncommon for the key to be generated during execution, preventing you from finding the correct key (as it is *not* written in the binary).

I think that the best way to do that is follow the binary's execution stepping **over** at first sight (to get a better idea of that piece of code) and only then go stepping **into** the calls.

If you're lucky (*and the developer was lazy*), you will find a point where the key is strcmp'ed (or something like that) with the input string, relieving you from the task of digging deep into the key generation algorithm.